# How to resolve OOM issues when training neural network on GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm training a neural network with TensorFlow on an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1080 Ti. My CPU has 32 GB RAM.
The network has only 1 hidden layer with weights of shapes [16788,10000] and [10000, 1478] respectively. Mini-batch size = 256.

```
for epo in range(self.epochs):
    loss_sum = 0        
    for mini_count in (range(len(mini_batches_x1_train))):
        batch_x1 = tf.one_hot(mini_batches_x1_train[mini_count], self.voc_size).eval()
        batch_x2 = mini_batches_x2_train[mini_count][0].toarray() 
        batch_x = np.concatenate((batch_x1, batch_x2), axis = 1)

        batch_y = mini_batches_y_train[mini_count]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y).reshape(len(batch_y),1)  #for tf.nce_loss()
        _, mini_loss = sess.run([optimizer,loss], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        loss_sum += mini_loss

    avg_loss = loss_sum/len(mini_batches_x1_train)
    print("\nEpoch", epo+1, " completed at ",time.ctime(time.time()), " | Epoch Loss = ", avg_loss)
```

After successfully completing 3 epochs, the following error pops up:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16788,10000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Does more epochs require more memory? Where could I be possibly wrong? Kindly suggest possible solutions to overcome this.

Comment: This is really a non-answer, but I've had the same problem in Tensorflow-as-a-Keras-backend. I just wound up switching the backends out - this is a TF problem, not a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

When training on GPU, Tensorflow tries to load as much as it can to GPU VRAM so it is fast and does not bottleneck by accessing the RAM data from GPU too often.
So if the network does not fit the VRAM, you have basically multiple options.

1. The most widely used option is to lower the batch size. Try 128 or 64 (it is advised to keep batch size power of 2, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483233/is-using-batch-size-as-powers-of-2-is-faster-on-tensorflow)). Some State-of-the-Art architectures are so huge you can have only batch size=1 even on GTX 1080Ti.
2. Change the architecture and make it smaller.
3. Run model on CPU (which you probably don't want to because of performance).
4. Change the Optimizer to some that uses lower memory. E.g. ADAM optimizer, which is used to obtain SOTA performance, adds its own variables to every layer and thus the whole model consumes more memory than some simpler optimizers. Although usually don't want to change the optimizer and just lower the batch size.

Comment: If mini-batch size was a problem, OOM should have occured during the very first epoch. But, as I have mentioned, it did complete 3 epochs before OOM. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.