# Explanation of dimension of input in a transformer model

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, transformer-model, attention-model

[Model Architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phGpE.png)

Hey,
I was trying to code the Transformer architecture from scratch as a part of my project. I wanted to ask that, what does the batch-size refer to in the dimension of the of the input matrix of the encoder.

I have us the attached model architecture as my reference. Let me consider the example of an essay document. The `seq-len` refers to the maximum length of the sentence inside the document and the `embedding-size` refers to the size of the word embedding of each word of the sentence. In that case does `batch-size` refer to the number of sentences in the document ?

Answer (score 0):

When you train an neural network, generally you input your dataset in batches. This means your dataset is divided in slices of equal size which are iteratively passed. [8, 16, 32, 64...](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/what-is-the-advantage-of-keeping-batch-size-a-power-of-2) are common batch sizes for training. When running inference, the batch size depends on the application and the user input. There is a trade-off between using larger or smaller batch sizes, which has been extensively discussed ([link](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8560/how-do-i-choose-the-optimal-batch-size), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050753/how-big-should-batch-size-and-number-of-epochs-be-when-fitting-a-model-in-keras)).

Specifically answering your question, `batch-size` refers to the batch size you choose in your implementation. Any value between 1 and your dataset size is technically valid (although in practice very large sizes won't fit into memory).