# Is there a good rule out there to choose an appropriate batch size?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pytorch

The common heuristic is to ensure it is as big as your acceleration hardware allows it. Nevertheless, when training on a small dataset with a large batch size it appears that the training is inefficient because each epoch only has a small number of steps, which would prevent a good enough number of updates in order to make the training converge.

Comment: It's absolutely perfect if your whole dataset fits the memory. Because then you'll compute the gradients that consider errors from all the data, and you will step in the *right* optimization direction

Comment: The paper you attached doesn't seem to prove that large batch size is bad, they show that it becomes pointless to increase it infinitely, because a large enough batch size already contains most of data variety, and adding more samples is only a waste of computational power

Comment: This essentially boils down to the tradeoffs between stochastic (single item batch) and batch (full dataset batch) gradient descent. The advantages of the former are that the jitter allows it to escape local optima in what is most likely a massively non-convex parameter space. The advantages of the latter are that each step is in the "optimal" direction (possibly towards a local optima). Mini-batch gradient descent weighs these tradeoffs, and generally provides a slight speedup in terms of efficiency (compute time scales slightly less than linearly with increasing batch size at first)

Comment: So selection of the optimal batch size would require knowing something about the non-convexity of the search space. In general, this is a hard thing to know. I'd recommend the empirical approach tested on your specific dataset and model architecture, though I'd guess that unless you have a distributed compute cluster the performance of the training will be fairly insensitive to the magnitudes of batch size changes you can test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How big should batch size and number of epochs be when fitting a model in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050753/how-big-should-batch-size-and-number-of-epochs-be-when-fitting-a-model-in-keras)

Comment: I have seen works like [this][1] one that go deep into the subject. Does anyone know about other similar solutions??


  [1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06162

Comment: I disagree that it's perfect if the whole dataset fits into memory. If a smaller batch size also yields the same gradients because there is ~zero incremental information in the full dataset vs a single batch, then you'd be better off training with smaller batches to save money on hardware.

Comment: For deep learning, I think that the jitters of small batch training DO NOT help break local optima. Local optima essentially do not exist in deep learning given we are dealing with spaces with millions of dimensions. If jittering were useful, you could also directly inject noise in a controlled way rather than reducing batch size.