# Is there anything to increase the accuracy of this predictive model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I want to improve the accuracy of my trained model. I tried to create an ML model to predict whether a test sample belongs to someone with or without disease, based on the gene expression profiling, if it is possible at all.

I looked up some resources online and tried to write some code and here I am, stuck at around ~69% accuracy (output below)

```
Epoch 1/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 106s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6041 - accuracy: 0.6888 - val_loss: 0.6004 - val_accuracy: 0.6928
Epoch 2/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 106s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6016 - accuracy: 0.6905 - val_loss: 0.5996 - val_accuracy: 0.6881
Epoch 3/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 108s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6013 - accuracy: 0.6912 - val_loss: 0.5994 - val_accuracy: 0.6934
Epoch 4/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 105s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6013 - accuracy: 0.6913 - val_loss: 0.5996 - val_accuracy: 0.6881
Epoch 5/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 109s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6010 - accuracy: 0.6919 - val_loss: 0.5999 - val_accuracy: 0.6949
Epoch 6/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 111s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6009 - accuracy: 0.6917 - val_loss: 0.5998 - val_accuracy: 0.6937
Epoch 7/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 133s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6913 - val_loss: 0.6000 - val_accuracy: 0.6894
Epoch 8/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 132s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6014 - accuracy: 0.6918 - val_loss: 0.5987 - val_accuracy: 0.6959
Epoch 9/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 121s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6007 - accuracy: 0.6925 - val_loss: 0.5994 - val_accuracy: 0.6946
Epoch 10/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 126s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6007 - accuracy: 0.6929 - val_loss: 0.6000 - val_accuracy: 0.6941
Epoch 11/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 137s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6019 - accuracy: 0.6918 - val_loss: 0.5999 - val_accuracy: 0.6883
Epoch 12/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 136s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6009 - accuracy: 0.6925 - val_loss: 0.5985 - val_accuracy: 0.6957
Epoch 13/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 137s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6013 - accuracy: 0.6922 - val_loss: 0.5987 - val_accuracy: 0.6958
Epoch 14/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 138s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6006 - accuracy: 0.6931 - val_loss: 0.5996 - val_accuracy: 0.6939
Epoch 15/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 137s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6006 - accuracy: 0.6928 - val_loss: 0.6001 - val_accuracy: 0.6868
Epoch 16/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 136s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6007 - accuracy: 0.6927 - val_loss: 0.5990 - val_accuracy: 0.6956
Epoch 17/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 138s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6008 - accuracy: 0.6926 - val_loss: 0.6003 - val_accuracy: 0.6921
Epoch 18/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 138s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6011 - accuracy: 0.6918 - val_loss: 0.5992 - val_accuracy: 0.6892
Epoch 19/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 138s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6010 - accuracy: 0.6924 - val_loss: 0.6000 - val_accuracy: 0.6886
Epoch 20/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 137s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6007 - accuracy: 0.6925 - val_loss: 0.6001 - val_accuracy: 0.6885
Epoch 21/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 141s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6012 - accuracy: 0.6912 - val_loss: 0.5990 - val_accuracy: 0.6896
Epoch 22/100
45049/45049 [==============================] - 138s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6010 - accuracy: 0.6917 - val_loss: 0.5994 - val_accuracy: 0.6889
12514/12514 [==============================] - 21s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5988 - accuracy: 0.6957
ANN Test accuracy: 0.6957491040229797
```

As for what I've written, I'll attach the code down below, to make things clearer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Load data from the dataset file
dataset_file = 'concatenated_dataset.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_file)

# Check if there are any missing values in the 'VALUE' column
if df['VALUE'].isnull().any():
    # Handling missing values with SimpleImputer
    imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
    df['VALUE'] = imputer.fit_transform(df['VALUE'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Split the data into features (X) and target variable (y)
X = df['VALUE'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['Target'].values

# Step 2: Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Step 3: Feature Scaling (optional, but recommended for neural networks)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Step 4: Build the ANN model
input_dim = X_train_scaled.shape[1]

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=256, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_dim,)),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.1),
    layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')  # For binary classification
])

# Step 5: Compile the model
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Step 6: Train the ANN model with early stopping
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32,
                    validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Step 7: Evaluate the ANN model on the test set
ann_loss, ann_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)
print("ANN Test accuracy:", ann_accuracy)
```

How can I improve the ANN test accuracy from 69% to around 90%?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a programming problem, you are probably asking here because you have code, but designing a model is fundamentally not a programming problem.

Comment: This might be of value: [How big should batch size and number of epochs be when fitting a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050753/how-big-should-batch-size-and-number-of-epochs-be-when-fitting-a-model)

Answer (score 0):

- Tune your `Hyperparameters` using `RandomizedSearchCV` or `GridSearchCV`,, etc.
  Probably this will help you increase your accuarcy but 69-> 90, that depends on the data as well , how you process the data, handling outliers or manny more..  and  also model you choose.
- Don't use `validation split` in your `fit` method, You have scaled the training data and validation splits takes data from that scaled training data, validating set will then have information of training data.
- There is a reason you use `fit_transform` on training set and `transform` it on other sets.
- create separate set for validation, `transform` on basis of x_train. use that set in `validation_data`